# angular javascript ng-model not working

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angular-ngmodel, angularjs-ng-model

Here is a subsection of my project:

```
<div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4">
    <checked-input
     pholder="{{'publications-customDomain' | translate}}"
     class="add-publisher-input"
     ng-model="customDomain.text"
     icon="glyphicon-globe"
     type="publicationCustomDomain"
     page="publications">
    </checked-input>
</div>
<div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4">
    <button ng-if="isBtnClassDisabled===false" class="add-domain btn btn-primary" ng-click="vm.addUserPublisher(currentTab)">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>{{'publications-addDomain' | translate}}
    </button>
</div>
```

The way this works is, the `checked-input` validates whatever is typed in to ensure that it is a URL, and once it is validated, `isBtnClassDisabled` becomes false, so that the button in the second div appears, and you are able to click it. This calls the function `vm.addUserPublisher`, however, when I try to log `this.scope.customDomain` (the `ng-model` of the `checked-input`) from the controller, the console returns `undefined`. Can anyone explain why? Thanks.

Edit 1 - My controller looks as follows:

```
class mainPublicationsCtrl {
    private scope: any;
    private timeout: any;
    private modal: any;
    private route: any;
    private http: any;
    private mainScope: any;
    private selSiteServ: any;
    static $inject = ['$scope'];

    constructor($scope, $timeout, $http, $modal, $route, selSiteServ) {
        $scope.vm = this;
        $scope.isBtnClassDisabled = true;
        $scope.selectedItem = 0;
        $scope.countOfTabs = 1;
        $scope.customDomain = {
            text: ""
        }
        this.scope = $scope;
        ...
        addUserPublisher(tab: any) {
            console.log(this.scope.customDomain.text);
        }
        ...
 }
```

Edit 2 - The `<checked-input>` directive is defined as follows:

Template:

```
<div>
  <div class="input-info-wrap">
    <div class="input-inform state-normal"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="input-group">
    <span ng-if="icon != '' && !isFaIcon"
          class="input-group-addon glyphicon {{icon}} icon-inline btn-item">
    </span>
    <span ng-if="icon != '' && isFaIcon"
          class="input-group-addon fa {{icon}} fa-input-label-size icon-inline btn-item">
    </span>
    <input type="text" 
           class="form-control btn-item form-tab-input" 
           placeholder="{{pholder}}"
           ng-model="model"
           maxlength="20">
    <span class="input-group-addon glyphicon glyphicon-asterisk input-state"></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Javacript:

```
class checkedInput implements ng.IDirective {
  public link: (scope: ng.IScope, element: ng.IAugmentedJQuery, attrs: ng.IAttributes) => void;
  public templateUrl = 'partials/directives/checked-input.html';
  public scope = { 
    model: "=",
    icon: "@",
    pholder: "@",
    type: "@",
    page: "@",
    num: "@",
    gstab: "=",
    gsrow: "=",
    tab: "=",
    isFaIcon: "="
  };
}
```

Comment: What if you just log `scope.customDomain`?

Comment: the controller is defined as a class, so I'm not sure that would work, I'll try it anyway. I'll add it to my original post as an edit.

Comment: <checked-input> is a directive you wrote? If so, can you post it in the question.

Comment: @VSO updated to include further information.

Comment: Thanks. I don't see what's wrong, but hopefully it will help others looking at the question.

Comment: we need the javascript declaration of the directive checked-input, not only the template.

Comment: @CyrilGando sorry, I've included that now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using a template for the `checked-input` directive. Define the `ng-model` within the directive's template instead of explicitly on the HTML.